# Cómo Mostrar páginas web sin conexión en IOS con XCODE

Tags: ios

Cómo mostrar páginas web sin conexión? 
En android es: `file:///android_asset/yourfile.html` 
Pero, ¿cómo se lo hace en `iOS`?

Estoy utilizando `xcode`.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener una URL desde los recursos locales de la aplicación, deberías usar el método `URLForResource` de la clase `NSBundle`.

**Swift 3**

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "nombre_archivo", withExtension: "html")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Ref: Esta es una traducción de la respuesta por [@rintaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3804019/rintaro) en [SO en Inglés aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift#26647637).

Comment: ¿Como seria con un archivo con extensión .jpg?

Comment: Sólo debes cambiar el valor de `withExtension` a `jpg` para obtener la ruta física sin embargo al webView tendrás que añadirla dentro de un HTML, como puedes verlo en este ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093885/4933141